# When does TeX update \pagetotal dimension and when does TeX update \tracingpages result?

Tags: tex-core, page

I am confused with the page builder in TeX:

1. When does TeX update `\pagetotal` dimension?
2. when does TeX update `\tracingpages` result?
3. Why doesn't TeX update both of them at the same time?

The followings are some testing code and the log:

```
\documentclass{article}

\tracingpages=1

\newcommand\mypagedim[1]{%
  \message{------------------ \unexpanded{#1} ----------------^^J}%
  #1%
  \message{\string\pagetotal=\the\pagetotal\space\string\pagegoal=\the\pagegoal^^J}%
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcommand\myloghrule{%
  \message{------------------------------------------------^^J}%
}

\begin{document}

\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{A\par}
\mypagedim{B\par}
\mypagedim{C\par}
\myloghrule

\newpage
\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{\leavevmode}
\mypagedim{A\par}
\mypagedim{\leavevmode}
\mypagedim{B\par}
\mypagedim{\leavevmode}
\mypagedim{C\par}
\mypagedim{\leavevmode}
\myloghrule

\newpage
\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\mypagedim{A\par}
\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\mypagedim{B\par}
\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\mypagedim{C\par}
\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\myloghrule

\newpage
\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{\penalty 10000\relax}
\mypagedim{A\par}
\mypagedim{\penalty 10000\relax}
\mypagedim{B\par}
\mypagedim{\penalty 10000\relax}
\mypagedim{C\par}
\mypagedim{\penalty 10000\relax}
\myloghrule

\newpage
\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{A\par}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{B\par}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{C\par}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\myloghrule

\newpage
\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\vskip 12pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\vskip 12pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\vskip 12pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\myloghrule

\newpage
\message{^^J}

\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\vskip 12pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\vskip 12pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\vskip 12pt\relax}
\mypagedim{\penalty 0\relax}
\mypagedim{\hrule height 1pt\relax}
\myloghrule

\end{document}
```

```
 
------------------ A\par  ----------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=0.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ B\par  ----------------
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ C\par  ----------------
% t=22.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------------------------------------
% t=34.0 plus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=34.0 plus 2.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[1]
 
------------------ \leavevmode  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ A\par  ----------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \leavevmode  ----------------
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ B\par  ----------------
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \leavevmode  ----------------
% t=22.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ C\par  ----------------
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \leavevmode  ----------------
% t=34.0 plus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------------------------------------
% t=46.0 plus 3.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=46.0 plus 3.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[2]

------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ A\par  ----------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ B\par  ----------------
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
% t=22.0 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ C\par  ----------------
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
% t=34.0 plus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------------------------------------
% t=34.0 plus 2.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[3]

------------------ \penalty 10000\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ A\par  ----------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 10000\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=10.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ B\par  ----------------
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 10000\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ C\par  ----------------
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 10000\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=34.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------------------------------------
% t=34.0 plus 2.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[4]

------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ A\par  ----------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=16.83331pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=16.83331pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ B\par  ----------------
% t=17.83331 plus 1.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=24.66663pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=24.66663pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ C\par  ----------------
% t=25.66663 plus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=32.49994pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=32.49994pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------------------------------------
% t=33.49994 plus 3.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=33.49994 plus 3.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[5]

------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \vskip 12pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \vskip 12pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \vskip 12pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------------------------------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=23.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=36.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=49.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=49.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[6]

------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \vskip 12pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=0.0pt \pagegoal=16383.99998pt
------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=22.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \vskip 12pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=22.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
% t=23.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=35.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=35.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=35.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \vskip 12pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=35.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \penalty 0\relax  ----------------
% t=36.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=48.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
\pagetotal=48.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------ \hrule height 1pt\relax  ----------------
\pagetotal=48.0pt \pagegoal=550.0pt
------------------------------------------------
% t=49.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=49.0 plus 1.0fil g=550.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[7]
```

Comment: If i understand the question, these calculations are part of the page builder. There is places where TeX exercise the page builder, roughly speaking when adding something to the current page. In your example this is after `\leavevmode` and after `\par` and for `\mypagedim{A\par}` just before insert A and after `\par`.

Comment: [TeXbytopic](https://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf#page=228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. TeX updates `\pagetotal` whenever it "exercises the page builder", which is when TeX moves all items on the "contribution list" to the "current page". The contribution list is the stuff that TeX hasn't yet considered adding to the next page. The current page is the stuff that TeX has considered adding to the next page (but may not actually end up on the next page). On page 122, the TeXBook lists the situations in which TeX exercises the page builder:

   > (a) At the beginning or end of a paragraph, provided that this
   > paragraph is being contributed to the main vertical list. (b) At the
   > beginning or end of a displayed equation within such a paragraph. (c)
   > After completing an `\halign` in vertical mode. (d) After contributing
   > a box or penalty or insertion to the main vertical list. (e) After an
   > `\output` routine has ended.

   However, note that TeX discards discardable items being moved to the current page when there are no boxes (or rules) on the current page, so the `\pagetotal` does not necessarily increase at these times.
2. TeX logs a `\tracingpages` line whenever a legal breakpoint is added to the current page. In particular, TeX usually outputs `\tracingpages` lines after interline penalties, or after interline glue not following interline penalties, because such items are legal breakpoints, at least in the absence of `\vadjust`. However, TeX does *not* output `\tracingpages` lines after the hboxes representing lines of a paragraph, because boxes are never legal
   breakpoints.
3. The last point above explains why the `\pagetotal` value is ostensibly out of synch with the `\tracingpages` lines in some of your examples: The last item contributed to the current page by a paragraph is an hbox representing the last line (assuming `\vadjust` does not appear in the last line). After the paragraph, the height of this hbox will be incorporated into the `\pagetotal`, but there is not a legal breakpoint *after* that hbox, so no `\tracingpages` line will include its height.

   Your other examples can be explained by determining at which points the page builder is exercised, and at which points the page builder moves a legal breakpoint from the contributions list to the current page. In particular, note that rules and skips do not exercise the page builder, but penalties do. You might find `\showlists` helpful.

Here's a simple example which I've annotated to explain all the essential
details. Note that the order I write steps in might not be the order that TeX *actually* does them.

```
\tracingpages=1
\hbox{A}
% 1. \hbox{A} added to contribution list, which causes...
% 2. Page builder exercised.
%   2.a. \topskip glue added to current page. No \tracingpages line is logged,
%        because the \topskip glue is not preceded by a nondiscardable item, so
%        it is not a legal breakpoint.
%   2.b. \hbox{A} moved to current page.
%   2.c. \pagetotal calculated based on \topskip and height of A.
\hbox{B}
% 1. Interline glue added to contribution list.
% 2. \hbox{B} added to contribution list, which causes...
% 3. Page builder exercised. 
%   3.a. Interline glue moved to current page. This is a legal breakpoint, so
%        a \tracingpages line is logged.
%   3.b. \hbox{B} moved to current page.
%   3.c. \pagetotal increased by depth of A, plus interline glue, plus height
%        of B.
\vskip1pt
% 1. \vskip1pt added to contribution list. The page builder is *not* exercised,
%    so a \tracingpages line is not yet logged.
\par
% 1. Page builder exercised.
%   1.a. \vskip1pt moved to current page. This is a legal breakpoint, so
%        a \tracingpages line is logged.
%   1.b. \pagetotal is increased by the depth of B plus 1pt.
\hbox{C}
% 1. Interline glue added to contribution list.
% 2. \hbox{C} added to contribution list, which causes...
% 3. Page builder exercised. 
%   3.a. Interline glue moved to current page. This time, the interline glue is
%        not a legal breakpoint, because it is preceded by a discardable item,
%        so no \tracingpages line is logged.
%   3.b. \hbox{C} moved to current page.
%   3.c. \pagetotal increased by interline glue plus height of C.
\bye
```

Note that I've used `\par` to force exercising the page builder without
adding anything to the main vertical list. `\par` is often redefined, so you
should usually use `\endgraf` (which is simply an alias for the primitive
`\par`) for this purpose.

Comment: `\vskip1pt` is a glue, hence a legal breakpoint. Why `\tracingpages` is not logged at once?

Comment: @L.J.R. `\tracingpages` lines are logged whenever breakpoints are added to the current page, not the contributions list. `\vskip1pt` adds 1pt of glue to the contributions list, but explicit skips do not exercise the page builder, so the glue isn't moved to the current page until after the `\par` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

According to TexByTopic

```
"The main vertical list of TEX is divided in two parts: the ‘current page’ and the list of
‘recent contributions’. Any material that is added to the main vertical list is appended
to the recent contributions; the act of moving the recent contributions to the current
page is known as ‘exercising the page builder’."
```

When you place only hrules and vskips, they all remains in ‘recent contributions’ list, and size of current page is not updated. Only at finish point page builder is exercising and they are put in main page. When you place material like boxes or penalties they are moved almost immediately on the main page.